# R summing up specific rows and columns

Tags: r, sum

I'm new to R and having issues with rowSums and colSums

My data set (called 'table') looks like this

```
     0 0.2 0.25 0.4 0.6 0.75 0.8  1
  0 92  34    1  19  23    0  16 17
  1  7  18    0  27  33    0  16 16
  2 12   8    0   7  16    0  14 25
  3  2   9    0   5   8    1   9 11
  4  0   1    0   3   3    1   1  7
  5  2   0    0   0   2    0   0  1
  6  0   0    0   1   0    0   0  5
  7  0   1    0   0   0    0   0  1
```

What I'm trying to do is simplify the table such that it will eventually look like

```
    0   >0
 0

>0
```

As in clump all values that are [0,0] [0, greater than 0] [greater than 0, 0] [greater than 0, greater than 0] to result in a 2x2 table

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample output? I'm having trouble understanding how you would like to select the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- as.matrix(read.table(text=
 "92  34    1  19  23    0  16 17
  7  18    0  27  33    0  16 16
  12   8    0   7  16    0  14 25
   2   9    0   5   8    1   9 11
   0   1    0   3   3    1   1  7
   2   0    0   0   2    0   0  1
   0   0    0   1   0    0   0  5
   0   1    0   0   0    0   0  1",
 header=FALSE))
dimnames(x) <- list(0:7,
c(0,0.2,0.25,0.4,0.6,0.75,0.8,1))
res <- matrix(c(x[1,1],sum(x[-1,1]),
         sum(x[1,-1]),
         sum(x[-1,-1])),
       nrow=2,
       dimnames=list(c("0",">0"),
       c("0",">0")))
## double-check:
all.equal(sum(x),sum(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into basic R matrix adressing first: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/matrix

Your compact matrix then ontains as follows:

```
reducedTable = matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2)
reducedTable[1,1] = Table[1,1]
reducedTable[1,2] = sum(Table[1,c(2:8)])
reducedTable[2,1] = sum(Table[c(2:8),1])
reducedTable[2,2] = Table[8,8]
```

Not on my PC right now so there may be typos in the code.

Comment: using `-1` is probably a little more general than using `2:8` (and `c()` is unnecessary here)

Comment: Thanks Ben - I actually did not know about the -1 construct! :)